# Keras отжирает память

Tags: python, память, машинное-обучение, keras, outofmemoryerror

У меня есть проблема с  керасом. Мне необходимо всякий раз после вычисления градиента на батче, считать loss для валидационного множества и для трейна  множества.

В API кераса указаны замечательные параметры:

```
steps_per_epoch, validation_steps
```

Они задают количество примеров на эпоху и валидацию соответственно. Таким образом, я хотел установить размер эпохи в 20 примеров, тем самым искусственно приравнять её к размеру `batch_size`. После этого я создаю `callback`, который отрабатывается всякий раз, после завершения обработки batch'а:

```
class LossHistory(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))
```

Но, к сожалению, такой метод не работает. Как только я устанавливаю вышеуказанные параметры (`steps_per_epoch`, `validation_steps`), начинает отъедаться память и машина зависает.

> Allocation of exceeds 10% of system memory

По поводу этой баги я написал [здесь](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10387). Пока что жду ответа. Но у меня есть проблема, которая, по-прежнему требует решения.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479557/keras-record-loss-and-accuracy-of-train-and-test-for-each-batch?rq=1) человек также сталкивался с проблемой и, судя по всему, не решил её.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В связи с тем, что простого ответа на этот вопрос нет, приходится костылить. Для этого, можно обратиться к членам класса `Callback`. Здесь лежит валидационное множество, на котором можно протестироваться. Делается это так:

```
class LossHistory(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.val_losses.append(self.model.evaluate(self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]))
```

P.s. `logs.get('val_loss')` считается после каждой эпохи. В связи с этим, в нём, на первом батче первой эпохи будет лежать `None`.